# postgresql convert utc to local time not doing in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a rails application with Postgresql as the default database. I have a table PromotionPipeLine with two datetime's columns start_date and end_date.
The time is saved in UTC format in the database column. I want to compare current time zone time with the saved columns time.But it seems to have some problem.
 I have defined the scope as given below

```
scope :changing_promotion, -> {where("(to_char(start_date At Time zone 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')='#{(Time.now).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')}') or (to_char(end_date At Time zone 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')='#{(Time.now).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')}')")}
```

and I am calling it in rails console as,

```
PromotionPipeLine.changing_promotion
```

Rails console showing me SQL query as,

```
SELECT "promotion_pipe_lines".* FROM "promotion_pipe_lines" WHERE ((to_char(start_date At Time zone 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')='2017-09-16 15') or (to_char(end_date At Time zone 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')='2017-09-16 15'))
```

and it returns nothing.
When I run above SQL query in pgAdmin it giving me expected record.

Comment: `Time.now` gives the time in the system timezone which is often not the same as `Time.now.utc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current time by using [Postgres own date/time](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html) functions instead of by passing it from rails:

```
SELECT "promotion_pipe_lines".* 
FROM "promotion_pipe_lines" 
WHERE 
  date_trunc('hour', start_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') = date_trunc('hour', current_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
OR 
 date_trunc('hour', end_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')) = date_trunc('hour', current_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
```

`date_trunc('hour', ...` truncates to the precision of one hour.

To adapt this to a ActiveRecord scope you would do:

```
class PromotionPipeLine

  # `scope` is just syntactic sugar to create class methods
  # use a regular class method if the defintion does not fit a lambda
  def self.changing_promotion
    where(
      SQL <<~  
        date_trunc('hour', start_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') = date_trunc('hour', current_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
        OR
        date_trunc('hour', end_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')) = date_trunc('hour', current_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
      SQL
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: `current_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` is only needed if postgres is set to some other time zone.